# call a method on a fragment in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

All I want to do is calling a function of my Fragment's class. But I can't seem to find a way to access the instance of my fragments which are in a ViewPager.

my activity's xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

There is no  so I can't call findFragmentById() (can I?)
also I don't know what to give to findFragmentByTag(), it always return null :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The pagerAdapter.getItem(int) method usually creates a new instance of the fragment, however, so what you can do is use a HashMap to store a reference to the already existing fragments.

```
// ViewPagerAdapter
private HashMap<Integer, Fragment> fragmentHashMap = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (fragmentHashMap.get(position) != null) {
        return fragmentHashMap.get(position);
    }
    TabFragment tabFragment = new TabFragment();
    fragmentHashMap.put(position, tabFragment);
    return tabFragment;
}
```

Then you can find your fragment to call its methods:

```
FragmentAdapter fa = (FragmentAdapter)viewPager.getAdapter();
TabFragment theFragment = (TabFragment)fa.getItem(index);
theFragment.customMethod(Object obj);
```

You will have to keep track of which fragment goes with which index because you cast them to their specific class in order to access their methods.

Answer (score 1):

The ViewPager should have an FragmentAdapter associated with it. So you can do something like:

```
FragmentAdapter fa = (FragmentAdapter)viewPager.getAdapter();
Fragment f = fa.getItem(index);
```

Comment: yes but getItem creates a new instance that's not what I want. unless I should take care of creating it once and then returning the same instance on subsequent calls? but I'm not sure that's the right thing to do

Comment: viewPagers don't do their own garbage collection so you should be recycling your fragments. see fragment pager adapter (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) if you want a self GCing pager

Comment: Don't use getItem() as it will create a new instance of your fragment. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:
http://tamsler.blogspot.fr/2011/11/android-viewpager-and-fragments-part-ii.html

I'm not sure there is no better way to do it...